# Spring 3.x and Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-envers

I'm having a problem getting Hibernate Envers to work in our environment. We are using Spring 3.x with LoadTimeWeaving. Below is our context file:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="autodetect"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.viridityenergy.vpower"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/database-test.properties"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="dataSourcePooled"
    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close"
    p:jdbcUrl="${database.url}"
    p:user="${database.username}"
    p:password="${database.password}"
    p:initialPoolSize="1"
    p:maxPoolSize="5"
    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="500"
    p:acquireIncrement="1"
    p:maxStatements="50"
    p:numHelperThreads="1"
    p:autoCommitOnClose="true"/>

<bean id="jpaAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:databasePlatform="${database.platform}"
    p:showSql="${database.showSql}"
    p:generateDdl="${database.generateDdl}"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:persistenceUnitName="TEST"
    p:persistenceXmlLocation="META-INF/persistence.xml"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSourcePooled"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">

  <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
    <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSourcePooled"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

Here is our persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="TEST" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert"
            value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>

    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update"
            value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>

    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete"
            value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>

    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update"
            value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>

    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove"
            value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>

    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate"
            value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>

  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The audit tables are setup correctly, but when an entity is persisted there are no records stored in the audit tables. There are only two fields that are audited. Also, because we are using loadTimeWeaving, when we run unit test, we are required to have -javaagent:/Users/TEST/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-instrument/3.0.3.RELEASE/spring-instrument-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar as a JVM argument so the loadTimeWeaving works.

Aside from Envers, everything else works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, so for anyone else who may be experiencing this, here it is. Envers was actually working all along. What I didn't realize was that in my unit tests, everything was wrapped in a single transaction and then rolled back. Envers will not commit to the audit table until the initial transaction commits and is complete.

The fix was to set the test up as an integration test without a rollback. Then my audit records started showing up.